# wp7 In-App View Directions in Map

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I wanted to ask is it possible to Show Directions in Map View (Bing) in Windows Phone 7. I want to show the route (lines) from present location to a specific location in my Map Component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had gone down the path of in-app routing, as per the [link Avijeet Singh provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681887.aspx), however I'd recommend against it. It took a significant amount of effort to handle real world scenarios and in the end the result was not as smooth or polished as the native Bing Maps experience. Having been there, unless there is a very compelling reason to display the routing information in app, I'd advise that you look at using [BingMapsDirectionTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394024%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). If you've implemented Fast Application Switching then the switch back / forth to the native maps won't be too jarring for user. Even having implemented routing in-app I ended up removing it and using the [BingMapsDirectionTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394024%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: I also found BingMapsDirectionTask as obvious choice (given my app development experience in android, where google maps are yet to come out with in-app direction viewing for android). But was curious if Bing has provided this functionality.

Comment: The Bing Maps don't provide this functionality as a one-liner but as Avijeet's link mentions, you can definitely do it. The web services are available and documented and the layering and drawing facilities of the Bing Maps control is rather rich. If you're just after a simple route drawn a map, sure, go for it. But getting an experience as full featured as the native one is lots of work. Direct the effort elsewhere within your app.

Comment: well, will go with your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Go through his link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681887.aspx

its for silverlight and will work on wp7 with some modifications.

here is another one if you just want to show a polyline on map control
http://guinnesslee.wordpress.com/2011/06/25/plotting-routes-onto-bing-maps-in-wp7-and-storing-it-an-obversable-collection/